# SVG linearGradient not showing on path (multiple browser)

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, svg

I can't figure out why this gradient isn't working in Chrome/Firefox/IE.

Its working in svg-editor (inside browser) and Inkscape.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="300" width="85" version="1.1">
 <defs>
  <linearGradient id="fill_bg" x2="0.5">
   <stop stop-color="#8e8e8e" offset="0"/>
   <stop stop-color="#d6d6d6" offset="0.59766"/>
  </linearGradient>
 </defs>
 <g>
  <path d="m3.5,16.5c12.5,6.6507,21,6.6507,33,0v271.47c-12.5,7.1172-22,7.1172-33,0v-135.74-135.73,0.00002,0.00001,0.00002,0.00001z" stroke="#352c2c" fill="url(#fill_bg)"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

The stroke is showing correctly, but the fill is missing completely (transparent),

Did I use something that browsers don't support?

Comment: I have referenced to your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38803429/gradient-of-svg-in-html-page-not-working --- maybe you have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, nevermind I had an CSS defintion for all path elements.

Once I removed that everything worked fine.

Comment: which definitions were those? your own or from bootstrap or sth? In my case gradient isnt working too, but I dont think I have css styles on path- or svg-elements. at least couldnt find them <:-)

Comment: I'm using Chrome 53.0.2785.143 (64-bit). Linear gradient in an SVG is not working. Strangely, in our production environment, Chrome is adding a cloudfront address where the linear gradient id is being referenced. Must be a bug. So, where the fill is for the linear gradient, ie: fill='url(%23linearGrad)', and the linear gradient has an id of 'linearGrad', Chrome adds fill='url(//d1cop1ikja3jwt.cloudfront.net'. Bizarre.