# gradient of <svg> in html page not working

Tags: css, html, svg, gradient

Referencing to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15487204/svg-lineargradient-not-showing-on-path-multiple-browser) question and the example used there:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="300" width="85" version="1.1">
 <defs>
  <linearGradient id="fill_bg" x2="0.5">
   <stop stop-color="#8e8e8e" offset="0"/>
   <stop stop-color="#d6d6d6" offset="0.59766"/>
  </linearGradient>
 </defs>
 <g>
  <path d="m3.5,16.5c12.5,6.6507,21,6.6507,33,0v271.47c-12.5,7.1172-22,7.1172-33,0v-135.74-135.73,0.00002,0.00001,0.00002,0.00001z" stroke="#352c2c" fill="url(#fill_bg)"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

On a ubuntu 16.04 system - when I include this *.svg into my html and open it in Firefox or Chrome - the gradient is not working (all other parts work ok)!

In contrast - when I open the *.svg as a file in Firefox or Chrome, the gradient is working as expected.

Note: I don't have any css that styles the svg- or path-tag and that might be a problem here.

Any ideas would be welcome!

Comment: Which browser do you open it with when you mention `browser` that's very vague?

Comment: Tested on Moz and Chrome - all applies for both. Thank you for your edits.

Comment: Does your html page have a <base> tag in it?

Comment: how are you including the svg in the html?

Comment: @RobertLongson yes it has - referencing to localhost

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto via jade (templating language) > `include`

Comment: That's why it doesn't work then.

Comment: @RobertLongson you were right! (I suppose you know) - could you give an explanation for that and maybe put it in an extra answer? I would like to mark it as best answer.